# A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api

Tags: react-native, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, upgrade

**since i upgraded gradle, when i try to open my react-native project i got this error in android studio **

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.
```

i am on mac

```
 buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1')
```

how can i resolve this problem and use android simulator?

thank you for your help :)

i tried to remplace compile(depreciated) by implementation but i got another problem

```
*Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'implementation' should be resolved. 
*
```

Answer (score 1):

Sanity Check

- use rvm / nvm to use a stable version of ruby / node. you should be on react 18 / java 11. You want a readme so other devs follow suite.

  ```
  brew tap homebrew/cask-versions
  brew install --cask zulu11

  # INSTALL RVM
  \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
  rvm install "ruby-2.7.6"
  rvm --default  use 2.7.6

  # INSTALL latest bundler
  gem install bundler
  bundle install

  # INSTALL NVM - https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm ( RELOAD TERMINAL AFTER INSTALL)
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.3/install.sh | bash
  nvm use 16
  ```

create /compile and run android project with a vanilla project from react-native

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

The following is going to be dated - review above discrepancies - check for following

1. android/build.gradle

```js
buildscript {
//    val gradle_android_version: String by extra
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 22
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
                // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
```

2. android/gradle.properties

```
    # Use this property to specify which architecture you want to build.
    # You can also override it from the CLI using
    # ./gradlew <task> -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64
    reactNativeArchitectures=armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64
    
    # Use this property to enable support to the new architecture.
    # This will allow you to use TurboModules and the Fabric render in
    # your application. You should enable this flag either if you want
    # to write custom TurboModules/Fabric components OR use libraries that
    # are providing them.
    newArchEnabled=false
    
    
    # Use this property to enable or disable the Hermes JS engine.
    # If set to false, you will be using JSC instead.
    hermesEnabled=true
```

3. android/settings.gradle

```
includeBuild('../node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin')
```

4. android/app/build.gradle

```
   apply plugin: "com.facebook.react" // add this

   dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android") 
   }
```

5. android/gradle/wrapper

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
```

There's quite a few extra changes I had to make to complete upgrade.
I deleted and cleaned up some extra guff. Can't be specific - but this worked for me.

Comment: Sanity Check indeed, thanks